# Apache 2 on Ubuntu Server 14.02 LTS - Apache won't load index.php

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php

I've set up a development environment in which I have a LAMP stack running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (runs on raspberry PI 2 B) and NetBeans on my PC and laptop. 
The problem starts when Im trying to execute my PHP code using FTP - all files are successfully uploading on the server but the server won't open it.
As soon as index.php is uploaded all I'm getting is a blank page and when I remove it everything back to normal (when Im typing ip address Apache shows me the files).

Sorry I know that this issue circulating around this forum for quite a long but I literally went though most of the solution suggested and non of the work.

Here is what I did so far:

1. Permissions and ownership for /var/www/html/ are set for www-data and the
   local user are set so they all can read,write,execute.
2. In mods-enabled > dir.conf following line was edited:
   DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you can do to troubleshoot the problem:

- Restart apache2:

  ```
  sudo apache2ctl restart
  ```
- Is the php5 module enabled? Look for php5.conf and php5.load in your mods-enabled directory. If they're not there, check to be sure they're in your mods-available directory, and enable the module with

  ```
  sudo a2enmod php5
  sudo apache2ctl restart
  ```
- Put a file named index.php and containing just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` into your /var/www/html directory, then browse to your website. Does that file also appear to be a blank page?
- Make sure the permissions and ownership of the index.php file allow the www-data user read access to the file.